# Write a LaTeX macro to differentiate the text

Tags: fonts, environments

I'm writing a report, and, for editorial purposes, I would like to use different fonts for each part of the report. I think I need to write a macro for it, but I don't know how to have this effect:

```
\begin{editLater}
//Use times font for this

\end{editLater}
```

Or

```
\begin{finalVersion}
//Use new roman font for this

\end{finalVersion}
```

Comment: Does it have to be Times and New Roman? Can it not be simply serif and sans-serif?

Comment: Sure! Just need to use different fonts for different parts of the text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the font switch macros `\rmfamily`, `\sffamily` etc. to switch the font inside the current group. You can define your own environment using `\newenvironment`.

Changing to a different totally different font locally is more complicated. You should load all font packages with the main font last and then need to rename certain font macros like `\rmdefault` below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Times
\usepackage{lmodern}  % LaTeX modern

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\newenvironment{editLater}{%
    \def\rmdefault{ptm}\rmfamily
}{}
\newenvironment{finalVersion}{%
    \rmfamily
    %\sffamily
}{}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{editLater}
\blindtext
\end{editLater}

\begin{finalVersion}
\blindtext
\end{finalVersion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @asgharashgari: Clad I could help. Note that you can accept one answer per question using the tick symbol on the upper left side of the answer. This concludes the question and assigns reputation to the answerer and to you. You can always change the accepted answer later.

Answer (score 3):

Same as Martin's answer but uses [`versions`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/versions) to switch over after editing to final version. I could not resist myself from posting, so kindly bear with me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} %% Provides dummy text
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{editLater}{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont}{\par}
\newenvironment{finalVersion}{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont}{\par}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{versions}
% \excludeversion{editLater} %% uncomment this line if you want final  version alone
%-------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
%% once you edit completely, change editLater to finalVersion inside braces.
\begin{editLater}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{editLater}
\begin{finalVersion}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{finalVersion}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

This uses `comment` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} %% Provides dummy text
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%-------------------------------------------------------
% \newcommand{\editLater}[2]{{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont #2}}
% \newcommand{\finalVersion}[2]{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont #2}}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{editLater}{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont}{\par}
\newenvironment{finalVersion}{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont}{\par}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{comment}
%\excludecomment{editLater} %% uncomment this line if you want final  version alone
%-------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
%% once you edit completely, change editLater to finalVersion inside braces.
\begin{editLater}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{editLater}
\begin{finalVersion}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{finalVersion}
\end{document}
```